# Oracle join query with like clause

Tags: oracle

I need to fetch a result with the combination of two tables.

```
select template_id 
from templatetbl 
where template_xml like '%889d-5765405edb42%'
```

On quering I am getting 24 records.

Now I want to fetch another set of records with the template id which I got earlier.

```
select * 
from sites 
where site_xml like '%templateid%'.
```

Templateid is the one which I got earlier.

I tried query like this

```
select * 
from sites 
where site_xml like (select template_id 
                     from templatetbl 
                     where template_xml like '%889d-5765405edb42%')
```

But getting error as  **single-row subquery returns more than one row** .

Please help on to combine both the queries

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select * 
from sites 
where site_xml like (select '''%'||template_id||'%'''
                     from templatetbl 
                     where template_xml like '%889d-5765405edb42%')
```

Comment: I think this will still have the `too many rows` error if subquery matches more than one row on `templatetbl`

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. A simple join where you build the `LIKE` string dynamically.

```
SELECT S.*
FROM   templatetbl T, sites S
WHERE  T.template_xml LIKE '%889d-5765405edb42%'
AND    S.site_xml     LIKE '%'||TO_CHAR(T.templateid)||'%'
```

Edit: Be warned though, this is probably no what you want. Because `templateid` of `1` will match `1`, `10`, `11`,... `21`,... `100` etc